# <abc with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on MVC 2, using Ajax.BeginForm as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ProcessResult(responsedContent) {
        var response = responsedContent.get_response();
        var result = response.get_object();
        alert(result);
    }
</script>
    <%using(Ajax.BeginForm("Test","Home", new AjaxOptions{ OnComplete = "ProcessResult"}))
{%>
   <input type="text" id="txtTest" name="txtTest" /> <input id="submitTest" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="3"/>
<%}%>


    public JsonResult Test(string txtTest)
    {
        return Json(txtTest);
    }
```

Could you please guide me how I handle the case users input `<abc` into the textbox txtTest? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try decorating the controller action you are posting to with the [`[ValidateInput]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult Test(string txtTest)
{
    return Json(txtTest);
}
```

Also if your application is compiled against .NET 4.0 you might need to add the following in your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks much, Darin. But it doesn't work. The Test function is not called yet. I get runtime error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data"  There is an exception in MicrosoftAjax.js